# Time complexity of distributed merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, distributed-computing

If there are  `N` elements (`N` very large) and we have to split the data to `K` machines to do a merge sort. What is the time complexity?

My attempt is that since each machine takes `N/K` data, the sorting on each machine takes `O(N/k*log(N/k))`. The k-way merge take `O(Nlogk)`. So total complexity is `O( N/k*log(N/k) + Nlogk`).

Could someone please confirm if above is correct? And if given `k << N`, can I simplify this further to just `O(N/k*log(N/k))`?

Comment: In the case where `k` is 1, your formula reduces to O(NlogN). That's certainly a good sign. When considering `k << N`, if we take `k` as a constant factor, then your formula also reduces to O(NlogN). In general, I don't think parallel processing affects the **time complexity** of an algorithm, it only affects the **wall clock time** of execution. And the wall clock time is governed by [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Comment: Yes, I did misunderstand the question, but some of the ideas may still be pertinent. Do you mean that each of the `K` arrays having `N/K` elements are to be sorted, then the resulting sorted arrays are to be sequentially merge-sorted (`K-1` operations) to produce the original array sorted? If so, the first step will be O(`K*(N/K)*log(N/K)`), or O(`N*log(N/K)`), but that's not relevant. It's the merging of those `N/K` element arrays where most of the work is done. Merge-sorting the first with the second will produce an array `a` with `2*N/K` elements...(cont.)

Comment: ...Merging the third into `a` will result in `a` having `3*N/K` elements in so on. The computational complexity of that entire sequential merging operation is O(`K*N*log(N)`), as compared to O(`N*log(N)`) to just sort the entire array. No?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was thinking that the first step is just  O(`(N/K)*log(N/K)`) because they would be done in parallel (but perhaps like the other comment said, this is not really the time complexity but rather the wall clock time).  As for the second part that's merging K sorted arrays of size N/K together, the [k-way-merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm) can be optimized to take O(`Nlogk`)

Answer (score 0):

First, your simplification is not correct.  Suppose that `K = O(sqrt(N))`.  Then the `O(N log(K))` bit is `O(N log(N))`.  But your simplified version says it should be `O(sqrt(N) log(N))` which is clearly incorrect.

Second, your estimate for a `K`-way merge is appropriate **IF** all of the merging happens on one machine.  But there are ways to distribute the merge. For example take even samples from each machine, and sort this sample.  Use that to figure out how to partition the data into `K` approximately equal samples.  Send those partitions to all of the machines, which split the data and sends each piece to the correct place.  Now each machine does a `K`-way merge on `O(N/K)` of the data.  How much data you want for that sample and what the overhead is, will depend how big `K` is relative to `N`.  But it isn't hard to find `K` and `N` such that the total time to do the work of sorting the data is `o(N)`.

But we now get a new bottleneck.  Dividing data, and reassembling it.  If you're doing this on a single machine, that's unavoidably `O(N)`.  But if you keep data on a distributed filesystem, sort it, and assemble the answer on another distributed filesystem, you can eliminate all of the bottlenecks!  (Operationally, at scale, you want everything distributed all of the time for exactly this reason.)